# I am trying to get all photos in current working directory.

Tags: php, foreach, gallery, jpeg, glob

I am trying to make a simple gallery script on my page for a photo booth. I have a tethered camera which is dropping pictures into a folder on my local site hosted with MAMP. Each folder is a different groups photos. Path to photos is ('/images/******'). First page searches the folders in my images directory and returns only the first image as a thumbnail/link to all folders containing all images for that group of people.

My structure is as follows.

1st page is:

```
$i = 1;
foreach (glob('images/*') as $dir) {
echo '<div id="strip' . $i . '" class="polaroid">';
// One div per directory                    
$p = 1;
foreach (glob($dir."/*.jpg") as $img) {
$p++;   
if ($p <= 2) {
echo "<a href='$dir'><img  src='$img'/></a>";       
} else {
}}
echo "</div>\n";
$i++;
```

This part works and takes the user to the directory with jpegs in it. which also contains a index.php file with the following code:

```
$dir = 'images/'.basename('/'.getcwd()).'/';
foreach (glob($dir."/*.jpg") as $img) 
echo $img;
{
echo "<img  src='$img'/>";      
}
```

This is where it fails. When I echo out $dir it shows the current relative path, but $dir in the foreach statement seems to be returning empty. This just returns an empty img tag. Any opinions where I am going wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the output of `echo $dir;` in the second page?

Comment: If I echo the $dir after i set it, as in right before the foreach loop I get 'images/225652/' being the directory i am in. However where I have inserted echo $img; i just get - <img src=''/>.

Comment: If you want to list the files in the current directory you could just set `$dir = '.';

Comment: Well talk about keeping your code simple. I flew right past that as a possibility. Took care of the problem. Thanks.

Comment: `glob` is a heavy function to use. I would recommend using alternative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to list the files in the current directory you have to set

```
$dir = '.';
```

You did set `$dir` to `/images/225652/` but you are already in this directory